# How to store the state and how to use shared preferences

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I just created a list view which consists of 2 list items as Colors and Temple. Colors and Temple again having a list items of Plans and Views. When I click on the Colors I should get the contents of Colors Plans and Colors Views. And when I click on the Temple I should get the contents of Temple Plans and Temple Views. How should I have to store the state and how can I get the contents using shared preferences.Please help me ..

Comment: post some code so people can understand your problem

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences object points to a file containing key-value pairs and provides simple methods to read and write them. Each SharedPreferences file is managed by the framework and can be private or shared.

Follow the link of the official developer site for more:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

You can write to Shared Preferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

and then read from Shared Preferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

And also dont forget to get a handle

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Hope this helps for now, do you need more support?